# "would not bury" vs "never buried"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following sentence (from the book A Force More Powerful by Peter Ackerman and Jack Duvall, page 31):

> They also killed a few officials whom the gravediggers **would not bury** as part of the boycott.

Does this sentence mean the following?

> They also killed a few officials whom the gravediggers **never buried** as part of the boycott.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The sentence means that [they] killed some government officials that the gravediggers **decided not to bury in protest** as part of the boycott.

Comment: Exactly. *Would* here is "volitional", meaning "were not willing to".